# What does this info mean when I fire `dpkg -l lxpanel`?

Tags: command-line, package-management, dpkg, versions, lxpanel

When trying to see the version of LXPanel and fire `dpkg -l lxpanel`, I get

```
~$ dpkg -l lxpanel
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  lxpanel        0.5.10+git20 i386         LXDE panel
```

Are there some errors that have to be solved?

Comment: No errors you have in there, its usual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ii  lxpanel        0.5.10+git20 i386         LXDE panel
```

- Desired status: install (`i`)
- Actual status: installed (`i`)
- Error: (nothing)
- Package name: `lxpanel`
- Version: `0.5.10+git20`
- Architecture: `i386`
- Description (short version): `LXDE panel`

> Are there some errors that have to be solved?

No. Not about this package as far as the package management is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

First `dpkg -l` does printing the `package-name-pattern`

> dpkg -l package-name-pattern - List installed packages matching
>   pattern. Practically speaking you have to use '*package-name-pattern*'
>   unless you know the fully exact name of the package.

you can get version name from `dpkg -l` also but That's not the usual way to get version of any package.Generally you can use `-v` or read its manpage for more information on how to get version name.

so for your case ,its `lxpanel -v`